# No such file or directory when using zip command

Tags: ansible, zip

I want to create a zip to package my function by using ansible, this is my playbook:

```
---
- name: build lambda functions
  hosts: localhost
    - name: Buid Zip Package
      command: zip -r functions/build/build-function.zip .
      args: 
        chdir: functions/function-package/
```

the function I want to package has its code inside `functions/function-package/`
I get this error:

```
> TASK [Buid Zip Package]
> ******************************************************** fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "zip -r
> functions/build/build-function.zip", "failed": true, "msg": "[Errno 2]
> No such file or directory", "rc": 2}
```

The paths are very correct, I don't know what else to check!
the playbook is in a file in the same level as the directory `/functions`

this is the strtucture of the files:

```
-- playbook.yml
-- /functions
  -- /build
  -- /function-package
    -- script.py
    -- lib
```

the zip is to be put inside /build

Comment: is there a reason why you do not use the [archive module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/archive_module.html)?

Comment: It's not working. I use ansible 2.3 and when I use archive module I get this error: `ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.`

Comment: can you give the part of the play using the archive module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `chdir: functions/function-package` on your task, then you're running the `zip` command inside the `functions/function-package` directory.  That means that the path `functions/build/build-function.zip` is probably no longer valid, since you're inside a child of the `functions/` directory.

Based on the information in your question, the appropriate path is probably `../build/`, like this:

```
- name: build lambda functions
  hosts: localhost
  - name: Buid Zip Package
    command: zip -r ../build/build-function.zip .
    args: 
      chdir: functions/function-package/
```

**Update**

If I replicate your directory layout:

```
$ find *
functions
functions/function-package
functions/function-package/script.py
functions/build
playbook.yml
```

And run this playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Build Zip Package
      command: zip -r ../build/build-function.zip .
      args:
        chdir: functions/function-package
```

It works just fine:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml
PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [Build Zip Package] **********************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

And the `.zip` file exists as expected:

```
$ ls -l ./functions/build/build-function.zip
-rw-rw-r--. 1 lars lars 209 Jan  3 08:19 ./functions/build/build-function.zip
```

Comment: Hopefully you understand the idea behind this answer and can apply it to your particular situation.

Comment: Perhaps you could update your question to show the layout of files?

Comment: See my update. I am unable to reproduce your problem.